# How to concurrently stream response back to the client in golang?

Tags: go, concurrency, grpc, grpc-go

I have below code in a method on server side which send streaming response back to the client.

```
var cfg = "..." // comes from request parameters
var clientId = "...." // comes from request parameters
var data = allCids.([]int64)
// can we run this in parallel with X number of workers?
for _, cid := range data {
  pd := repo.GetCustomerData(strconv.FormatInt(cid, 10))
  if !pd.IsCorrect {
    continue
  }
  resources := us.helperCom.GenerateResourceString(pd)
  val, _ := us.GenerateInfo(clientId, resources, cfg)
  if err := stream.Send(val); err != nil {
    log.Printf("send error %v", err)
  }
}
```

My confusion is can we make this to run in concurrent? or streaming always run in single threaded way?

Comment: You can do everything concurrently in goroutines except sending the message back on the server stream. That's not a great limitation, as you can have the goroutines send their results to a channel, and have your main goroutine read from that channel and send it on the server stream.

Comment: what is exactly "this" that you want to run concurrently?

Comment: @blackgreen sorry should have been clear earlier. I have a for loop `for _, cid := range data {` in my above code which sends streaming response back to client one by one sequentially. So I was thinking can we make that to run concurrently in parallel and send all those back to client? I also want to control the number of workers I want to run in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the work concurrent, but you can't make sending on the stream concurrent. From [`grpc-go` docs](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/concurrency.md):

> When using streams, one must take care to **avoid** calling either `SendMsg` or `RecvMsg` multiple times **against the same Stream from different goroutines**. [...]

So you can run your concurrent code in separate goroutines and send the output values on a common channel. The main stream handler then ranges over this channel and calls `stream.Send` **sequentially** — so keep in mind that all this is worth it only if the network response takes less than fetching the data.

The code looks like this:

```
// buffered, so the workers can send and exit immediately
out := make(chan <type of val>, len(data))

// you will have to close the out chan when all work is done
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(len(data))
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(out)
}()

for _, cid := range data {
  // don't close around the loop variable
  go func (id int64) {
    defer wg.Done()
    val, err := // obtain output value somehow
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    out <- val
  }(cid)
}

for val := range out {
  if err := stream.Send(val); err != nil {
    log.Printf("send error %v", err)
  }
}
```

The number of goroutines is the number of elements in `data`. If you want to control the number of goroutines, batch `data`. If you do this, adjust the channel buffer accordingly.